# how to use android studio and eclipse in same time with permanent environment variables

Tags: eclipse, environment-variables, development-environment

my question is how to use android studio and eclipse in same time with permanent environment variables . it's different of "in same time only " or "in the same project  " or  "using one sdk folder " .

thanks a lot .

Comment: Are you saying that when you have a synced project in both the environment variables are different?